# In Java Where does the PrintWriter write() method write the data

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
public class PrintWriterExample {  


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
             //Data to write on Console using PrintWriter  
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);    
      writer.write("Hello World");        
System.out.write(65);
System.out.write(' ');
System.out.flush();
System.out.close();

// writer.flush();  
  //writer.close();  

    }  
}
```

Iam having trouble  understanding write() method. Its description says that it Writes the specified byte to this stream. What do we mean by 'this stream'. Where is it written? Some kind of buffer??
What does it mean to pass System.out as argument to PrintWriter class constructor?
In this code where is my data buffered? Is some temporary memory created when i use writer.write() and System.out.write()?
Also when i tried to comment and uncomment flush and close methods randomly i got results that confused me.In this particular instance why doesnt  "Hello World" get printed on the screen even though i have flushed and closed the buffer. If you say that the buffers are different then when i uncomment writer.flush() and writer.close() then also i get the same result.

Comment: You create the print writer pointing to the system out stream. Or standard out or simply : the console. It is all there in your code. Just read all of the relevant javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), aka an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html), so you're calling the [`PrintWriter(OutputStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-) constructor.

It is equivalent to calling the [`PrintWriter(Writer out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-) with the following argument:

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out))
```

The [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) is injected for performance reasons.

> where is my data buffered?

In the `BufferedWriter`.

> why doesnt "Hello World" get printed

The `"Hello World"` text is sitting in that buffer, and since you never flush `writer`, it'll never be sent downstream to the `System.out` print stream.

> What does it mean to pass `System.out` as argument to `PrintWriter` class constructor?

It means that any text written to the `PrintWriter` will be forwarded to `System.out`. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-) says: *This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will **convert characters into bytes using the default character encoding**.*

> when i uncomment writer.flush() and writer.close() then also i get the same result.

That is because you already closed `System.out`, so it will not accept any more output. `PrintWriter` silently ignores the error thrown when you try. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) says: *Methods in this class **never throw I/O exceptions**, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking `checkError()`.*

---

**Solution**

Calling `close()` will automatically call `flush()`, so you don't need to call `flush()` before `close()`.

Calling `close()` on the `PrintWriter` will automatically call `close()` on `System.out`, so you don't need to do that.

Remove `System.out.flush();`, `System.out.close();`, and `writer.flush();`, and only call `writer.close();`.

Better yet, you should in general never close `System.out`, so just call `writer.flush();`, and leave it open.

Comment: Is this statement called implicitly? new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out))

Comment: System.out.write(65); does this line also create a new buffer to store the char 65?

Comment: @PranjalKanyal `PrintWriter(OutputStream out)` is a convenience constructor that calls `PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)))`. Go ahead and look at the source code of `PrintWriter` to see for yourself (easiest if you use an IDE). --- `System.out` is also buffered, for the same reason (performance).